# Minecraft plugin: JDA library conflict with Kotlin causing issues

Tags: java, kotlin, maven, minecraft, discord-jda

I'm currently working on a Minecraft plugin that uses the JDA library, the only problem is that JDA implements a Kotlin library that causes problems with another Kotlin plugin from the cloud because they are different versions.

The exact error i get, is this:

```
07:42:24 [WARNING] Exception encountered when loading plugin: SimpleCloud-Permissions
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method 'eu.thesimplecloud.clientserverapi.lib.promise.ICommunicationPromise eu.thesimplecloud.clientserverapi.lib.promise.ICommunicationPromise.then(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1)' the class loader net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader @5ce8d869 of the current class, eu/thesimplecloud/module/permission/PermissionPool, and the class loader net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader @5460cf3a for the method's defining class, eu/thesimplecloud/clientserverapi/lib/promise/ICommunicationPromise, have different Class objects for the type kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1 used in the signature (eu.thesimplecloud.module.permission.PermissionPool is in unnamed module of loader net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader @5ce8d869, parent loader 'app'; eu.thesimplecloud.clientserverapi.lib.promise.ICommunicationPromise is in unnamed module of loader net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader @5460cf3a, parent loader 'app')
    at eu.thesimplecloud.module.permission.PermissionPool.<init>(PermissionPool.kt:51)
    at eu.thesimplecloud.module.permission.service.bungee.BungeePluginMain.onEnable(BungeePluginMain.kt:32)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugins(PluginManager.java:266)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:298)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:67)
    at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
07:42:24 [INFO]
```

Is there a way to bypass this or a version that does not contain Kotlin?

Comment: How do you know they are different version and can you influence that?

Comment: The owner from the SimpleCloud-Permission plugin told me that. And it makes a bit sense.